# Error - System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

The error

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

comes up whenever I run the below code

```
            string btnString = @"SELECT FacultyName, Office, Phone, College, Title, Email FROM FACULTY WHERE FacultyName LIKE @name";

            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader sr;

            sc.Connection = (SqlConnection)Application["sqlConn"];
            sc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sc.CommandText = btnString;
            sc.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ddlFacultyName.Text;
            string strName = ShowFaculty(ddlFacultyName.Text);
            sr = sc.ExecuteReader();

            if (sr.HasRows == true)
                FillFacultyReader(sr);
            else
                Response.Write("<script>alert('No match found!')</script>");

            sr.Close();
            sc.Dispose();
```

The error is displayed at

```
sr = sc.ExecuteReader();
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: I see the connection is cached (in session state), could it be that a reader has been opened on this connection but not closed BEFORE the above code is called?

Comment: @neds Have you tried the method I posted below? If it solved the problem could you please mark it as answer? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Murat I have the tried the method you posted and it did not work I still get the same error

Comment: Seems to be that you make another request in your select before the first connection is not closed. Try the line I added to my answer and let us if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Better will be Change Your Code like this

```
using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("constr"))
{
  using(SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand ("sp",con))
  {


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use this code block in for, foreach or while repetition. And one more thing, did you open the connection before the command "sc.ExecuteReader()". most probably you use a repetition then you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you already have a dataAdapter or executeScalar open with the same connection above this code. There are two options to this: 
1. Take this code above the dataAdapter code block and keep it in separate

```
try 
{
conn.open(); 
//Your code here

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//exception handling
}
finally
{
conn.close(); 
}
```

or as stated by Ganesh_Devlekar. Also remember to close your DataReader
2. define the same connection in another sqlConnection type. That is:
if you have a connection like

```
SqlConnection conn  = New SqlConnection("your_connectionString");
//create another SqlConection variable
SqlConnection conn1  = New SqlConnection("your_connectionString");
//Use Conn1 for SqlDataReader
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add **MultipleActiveResultSets=true;** to your connection string as shown below?

```
<add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=XXXX;
Initial Catalog=XXXX; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
```

**Update:**
In your case, you might also try to close the connection by adding this line after sr.Close(); line:

```
sc.Connection.Close();
```